# How tot prove the inequality: $\lambda_{min}(S^TS)\lambda_k(A)\le\lambda(S^TAS)\le\lambda_{max}(S^TS)\lambda_k(A)$

Tags: matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

Let $A\in \mathbb{S}^n$ be PSD and let $S\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be nonsingular. How to prove that for any $k\in \{1,\cdots,n\}$, 
$$\lambda_{min}(S^TS)\lambda_k(A)\le\lambda(S^TAS)\le\lambda_{max}(S^TS)\lambda_k(A)$$
It seems that Weyl inequality can be used. But I just cannot figure it out.

Comment: What is $\lambda(S^TAS)$?

Comment: It stands for any eigenvalue.

Comment: the inequality can be failed. e.g. let $S$ be equal to the identity matrix. am I missing something?

Comment: I know it was a long time ago, but is it possible you meant $\lambda_k(S^TAS)$ instead of $\lambda(S^TAS)$?